# Aligning horizontally multiple div inside another without margins

Tags: html, css

I have 4 divs inside another in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MicheleC/TDLtJ/)**. I can't manage to remove the space between the divs of class `toolbarItem`,

html

```
  <div id="topPanelContainer">
    <div id="toolbar">
      <div id="toolbarItem1" class="toolbarItem"></div>
      <div id="toolbarItem2" class="toolbarItem"></div>
      <div id="toolbarItem3" class="toolbarItem"></div>
      <div id="toolbarItem4" class="toolbarItem"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#topPanelContainer {
    height: 30px;
    background: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
}
#toolbar{
    height:30px;
    width:800px;
    background:grey;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.toolbarItem {
    height: 30px; width: 100px;
    background: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I would expect the four div to stay one just after the other in place of:

[image]

Comment: hi ur saying for example it should look like on div instead of three divs...even though three divs in code

Comment: @codebreaker hi what I'm saying is: I can't see why in **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/RBqYR/)** there is no space between the two sub divs differently than mine

Comment: i hope @vikas Ghodke has solved ur issue check out his answer...

Comment: Another option could be just change in class and make it float:left. for class .toolbarItem {   
    
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    
    float: left;
}

Comment: @PM float:left what i tried for Michele it brings all the four divs together

Comment: @PM. thanks it also does the job, especially because I don't need them to be centered into the container div (they will fill it entirely so)

Comment: @codebreaker: If you see keep the margin/padding 0 and keep float: left, then all divs will try to align to left, and all will be together. See the changes in Fiddle created by Michele

Comment: Thanks Michele, glad to hear that it worked for you.

Comment: i know that's wat i was trying to say in my previous post anyway michele task is complete thanks for commenting @PM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Default inline-block adds some margin around the element.

You can remove this extra gap by replacing your html by the below code

```
<div id="topPanelContainer">
    <div id="toolbar">
        <div id="toolbarItem1" class="toolbarItem"></div><div id="toolbarItem2" class="toolbarItem"></div><div id="toolbarItem3" class="toolbarItem"></div>
        <div id="toolbarItem4" class="toolbarItem"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And to get all of them in to one line you need to add `float:left;` to `.toolbarItem`

```
.toolbarItem {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    background: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    float:left;
}
```

**[See Them Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/TDLtJ/4/)**

Check out this article for more info about this -- >> http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: A good reference for how to combat this problem: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: @RGraham Thanks for the article, included the link in my answer.

Comment: omg, you are saying that just putting all the div in one line will renove that space??? uaau. Sorry a question, (as I'm new to web devel), is there any reason why this happens? Is actually meant to behave like that? Btw, Thanks a lot.

Comment: also, using chrome's  `inspect element`, I can't see any margin in box model of the div.

Comment: This is the way inline works. Its just like the space between the words. And there are some other methods also to solve this issue, you can always set margin-right: -4px; to your inline divs, if you dont want to have all your divs in one line.